# Show that $f(x)=ax+b$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$ where $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuously differentiable function. Show that if $f$ satisfies:

$\frac{1}{2y} \int_{x-y}^{x+y}f(t)dt=f(x)$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R},y>0$ then there exists $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)=ax+b$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$

Attempt: Differentiating w.r.t $x$ on the given equation we get $\frac{f(x+y) - f(x-y)}{2y} = f'(x)$,

i.e $f(x+y) - f(x-y) = 2f'(x)y$, Differentiating w.r.t $y$ we get $f'(x+y) + f'(x-y) = 2f'(x)$. Since $f'$ is differentiable, Again differentiating w.r.t $y$ we have  $\ \ f''(x+y) - f''(x-y) = 0 \implies f''(x+y) = f''(x-y)$ from here we can conclude that $f''$ is constant. But after integrating I think I might get a second degree polynomial. So I'm stuck here, Help me out. Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: This has been asked and answered several times: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3229147/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3823153/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3585516/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3586457/42969 – all found with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B2y%7D%20%5Cint_%7Bx-y%7D%5E%7Bx%2By%7Df(t)dt%3Df(x)%24)

Comment: Okay thanks for the link, Help me close the question.